# Overriding JSP files in jar META-INF/resources unpredictable

Tags: jsp, maven, resources, taglib, meta-inf

I'm building a modular web application which has some Spring components packed inside a jar dependency (different module). This jar also contains some JSP resources like:

```
 - Module
     + src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/module/*.jsp
```

Now I want to override a specific JSP using the following structure in my application.

```
 - App
     + src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/module/menu.jsp
```

When running the application using `tomcat7:run` it will sometimes show the overridden `menu.jsp` but will any subsequent runs will end up with the old one.

Running with `tomcat7:run-war` was more promising. Most of the runs the new menu.jsp is shown. But when deploying the application to another Tomcat 7 instance the old menu is visible once again.

The menu.jsp is include using `pageContext.include("/module/menu.jsp");` which is called by a custom tag.

How can I make this overriding of resources more reliable? I'm totally clueless since it seems to be randomly working. I hope somebody can shed some light here.

---

Not sure if this is relevant but to be able to use component scanning I need to unpack the jar classes with the following plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <overWriteIfNewer>false</overWriteIfNewer>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>my.company</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my-dependency</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>**/*.class</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of hair pulling I came to realize I made a very simple mistake. I have now moved

```
- App
     + src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/module/menu.jsp
```

to the location

```
- App
     + src/main/webapp/module/menu.jsp
```

and everything works like expected.